# Symfony 4/Doctrine 2 - fetching real object not the proxy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, many-to-one

I have a following entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CourseLevelRepository")
 */
class CourseLevel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var CourseLevel
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\CourseLevel", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $nextCourseLevel;   


    ...
}
```

As you can see it builds a tree structure so any record can point to it's parent by ManyToOne relation of $nextCourseLevel.

Then I fetch the list of elements with the query in repository:

```
class CourseLevelRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, CourseLevel::class);
    }

    public function fetchFiltered(array $filters)
    {
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('cl');
        $builder->setFirstResult(0);
        $builder->setMaxResults(10)
        $builder->orderBy('cl.name', 'asc');

        return $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Let's assume following set of data:

```
id | next_course_level
-------------------------
1  | 2
2  | null
```

For that I will receive following objects:
- Object with id = 1, which is an object of App\Entity\CourseLevel (with the $nextCourseLevel set to object id = 2 which is a proxy)
- Object with id = 2, which is a proxy object.

That's happen probably because of relation - object with id=1 points to id=2 as the parent.

But how can I force to fetch all data as the real objects, not the proxies? Putting fetch="EAGER" does not change anything :(

Comment: May we know why such a use case? Why would you need "a real object" instead of proxy? A proxy is still a real object, it just extends your entity so it should be ephemeral to your application.

Comment: I have some of the fields of CourseLevel annotated with my custom annotation and further I process object based on that annotation. Having the proxy of object I have such data, but I don't have annotations anymore.

Comment: Lol you shouldn't be parsing annotations in the first place. You have full access to entity's class metadata from the entity manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join and select your association in order to get the object and not a proxy.

Check the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#joining-related-records).

Example from docs:

```
// src/Repository/ProductRepository.php
public function findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($productId)
{
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

$query = $entityManager->createQuery(
    'SELECT p, c
    FROM App\Entity\Product p
    INNER JOIN p.category c
    WHERE p.id = :id'
)->setParameter('id', $productId);

return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

*"When you retrieve the product and category data all at once (via a join), Doctrine will return the true Category object, since nothing needs to be lazily loaded."*